# How to test Fragment with Fragment Scenario?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-testing

I am trying to test a `Fragment` in isolation. To do this, I am trying `FragmentScenario`.

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing) offers a really good example here. But My test always fails because my fragment cast the activity to an interface at `onAttach`.

`FragmentScenario` luanches a container `Activity` which (obviously) does not implement the interface required by my fragment.

My question is how to get around this? How to I force the container activity to implement the interface I need? or Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe remove the casting on `onAttach` and replace with with a different method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a different approach. I ended up using `ActivityScenario` for the fragments that had callbacks to the Activity.

Created an AccountTestActivity in my Development build. The activity implements all of my various callbacks (LoginCallback, CreateAccountCallback, etc..) from the fragments that I wanted to test.

I don't want to open my classes for testing or add extra functions.

```
scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(AccountTestActivity::class.java).onActivity {
        logInFragment = LogInFragment()
        it.startFragment(logInFragment)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. However, are you able to check views after the fragment is loaded on your AccountTestActivity? I try to do the checking inside of the lambda block but the test just hangs there.

Comment: @WenhaoWu This code is meant to go into your **Before** setUp function where you prepare all the dependencies/mocks your tests require. Then you can interact with views in your **Test** functions. [simplified gist](https://gist.github.com/klemenk161/92f80e19a7624d7e99e64ef91fd21577)

Comment: i've tried some implementation that took this aproach but for me, the method startFragment() doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Comment: @aguiarroney startFragment() is just any custom public method you put in your activity, to commit the fragment and/or do some extra work there. Anyways, shared ViewModels should be used now instead of callbacks. :)

Comment: yeah, I realized that after posting this coment, but it's fine. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use a hook to assign the member, extend the fragment, override the hook to provide a mock of that interface. If not, use a DI to inject that into a public member and just assign a mock directly.

```
class MainFragment : Fragment {

   override fun onAttach(context:Context) {
       mViewInterface = provideViewInterface()
   }

   protected fun provideViewInterface() = activity
}

class TestMainFragment:MainFragment() {
   override fun provideViewInterface() = mock()
}
```

Comment: wow we have to go through all that just to test the fragment! This was really helpful! thank you soo much :D